# PHP how to access file from folder and how to download them

Tags: php

```
<?php
$dir_path = "./folder/";
if(is_dir($dir_path))
{
    $files = opendir($dir_path);
    {
        if($files)
        {
            while (($file_name = readdir($files)) !== FALSE) 
            {
                 if ($file_name != '.' && $file_name != '..'){
                echo "<a href=".$file_name.">".$file_name."</a><br>";
                #echo "<img src=".$file_name.">";
            }

            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Returns an array of files and directories from the directory . ... I wanted to easely access data in a certain directory using foreach. I came up with the following:
but it is not download

it say like this 
Object not found!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these cases first you need get files of directory like following:

```
$dir    = './FILE_FOLDER_NAME';
$files = scandir($dir);
unset($files[0]);
unset($files[1]);
```

Why we used unset, these code remove . and .. from $files variable and you have just file names.

Now you can show files with this approach:

```
foreach($files as $key => $value):
    $path_info = pathinfo($value); //RETURN FILE EXTENTION
    ?>
    <a href="DIRECTORY_PATH<?php echo $value; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $value; ?>
    <?php
endforeach;
```

If you want to delete a file can add new button to your foreach like this:

```
<button href="PHPSAMPLEFILE.PHP?file=<?php echo base64_encode ($value); ?>"><?php echo 'DELETE'; ?></button>
```

and in your PHP file:

```
$file = base64_decode($_GET['file']);
$path = './DIRECTORY_PATH/'.$file;
unlink($path);
```

Comment: is there any mechanize to delete file  from folder in this code

Comment: Your welcome, i will appreciate if you up vote and mark as best answer

Comment: whats is that function <?php echo __('DELETE'); ?>

Comment: use from <?php echo 'DELETE'; ?>

Comment: appreciate you Majid Abbasi